# Split phrase in n characters completing whole words in Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I've a .txt like this:

```
CAS ACCIDENT PÈNDOL TIBIDABO
 SN Per la mort d'una jove de 14 anys, Andrea, el 17/07/2010 a l'atracció del pèndol del Parc d'atraccions del Tibidabo
 BT ACCIDENTS
 RT PARCS D'ATRACCIONS
CAS ADIF
 SN El dia 5 de Maig es fan els primers registres a les seu d'Adif per esclarir un possible cas de malversació de fons públics durant les obres de l'Ave Madrid Barcelona. L'operació es va anomenar operació yogui. També per al presumpte desviament de diners o sobrecostos no explicats que han paralitzar les obres de La Sagrera (2016)
 BT CORRUPCIÓ
CAS AGRESSIÓ GUÀRDIA URBANA
 SN Per l'agressió que va rebre un guàrdia urbà (que està en coma) durant uns aldarulls produits arran d'una una festa il·legal a una casa okupada al carrer Sant Pere més Baix el 4F de 2006. Hi ha tres joves acusats de l'agressió. S'ha celebrat el judici el gener de 2008.
CAS APAGADA BARCELONA
 SN 16/03/2010
 BT TALLS ELECTRICITAT
```

I would like to match sentences starting with " SN " and then split in 220 characters not cutting whole words.

I find this `^ SN .{220}` for Find, but it split in the middle of words.

Thanks

Comment: What should happen if it is in the middle of a word?

Comment: As usual: 1) `^ SN .{220,}?\b` or 2) `^ SN .{0,220}\b`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a stop once you find the first space `^SN .{220}[^\s]*`, no sure if it is necessary but you can also add "or" (|) for ponctuation.

Comment: Thank's phoenixstudio, that works for me